What Are the Best Opening Strategies for Both Sides in Chess for a Returning Player?
I used to be an active chess player with a rating over 1300, but I stepped away from the game for a while to focus on other priorities. Now, I'm looking to get back into chess and improve my skills. Given my past rating, I'm looking for advice on the most effective opening strategies for White and Black against popular openings like the Ruy Lopez, Scotch Game, Queen's Gambit, King's Gambit, and Sicilian Defense.
I'm curious about the best approach to rebuilding my skill level. Should I focus on playing against chess engines and bots to practice specific scenarios and sharpen my tactics or is it more beneficial to play against human opponents to regain my understanding of human strategies?
What are the most helpful online resources, websites, forums, or YouTube channels for a player who is looking to get back into chess and improve from a 1300 level?

Please only post one question per question. For 1. you should for now focus on just following opening principles, while spending your time on tactics. For 2. see answer there: https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/7959/33999 For 3. see answers at https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/45140/33999 and https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/39875/33999

I don't think the advice and resources that should work for your specific case is any different from the advice that would apply to any other player at your skill level.
For openings, you probably want to start by returning to what you already know and expanding as you play and analyze games.
Don't waste your time playing games against bots. Engines are great analysis tools but a horrible simulation of how humans play chess

Yeah, I agree. Some bots, especially higher elo bots make completely illogical moves to our human perception. However, I have heard positives and negatives for playing against bots.
